# C# Progress bar - can't wrap my head around it

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have a program that takes loops through files in a folder, creates a new folder elsewhere with that file name, then puts a common file in that folder.  rinse repeat until we are done with whats in that folder (listed in a listbox).

I decided I want to be fancy and have a progress bar. I conceptually understand that I am increment the count by one (to the `listbox.items.count`) for each iteration.. which I have coded and works well.

I also understand that the `DoWork` event is what counts for the progress bar, how do I get the two to mesh? Do I pass a counter to the `DoWork` for each iteration?

I am just missing the bridge from my main code loop to the DoEvents counter.

Comment: `DoWork` has little to do with the progressbar, it is a BackGroundWorker method.  If that is what you are using, use the `ReportProgress` method to allow the UI to update the progess bar.  `DoEvents` is not involved

Comment: @marc_s OK, thanks for the -2, hope that makes you feel good.  Cheers.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I think I get it, I will play around with it.

Comment: I **did NOT** downvote you - I could now, just to prove what I'm saying .... (but I won't - your question's isn't bad or stupid or anything) - I only fixed a few typos and cleaned up your post a bit. Thanks for nothing, I guess....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backgroundworker as shown:

```
 BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(update_DoWork);
 worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(update_ProgressChanged);
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

You need a ProgressChangedEventHandler. Then you will need to use ReportProgress when you want to update the progress bar (this will be in the DoWork method). This method will call the ProgressChangedEventHandler.

```
int percentProgress = 10;
worker.ReportProgress(percentProgress)
```

An example of a ProgressChangedEventHandler:

```
 private void update_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           progressBar.Value = (e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
```